# Is there a good example of how to use SPARQL to replace a substring with another substring across a collection of triples?

Tags: sparql

I want to edit a set of URIs replacing a substring "iso-693" with "iso-639" using a SPARQL query. I am using `REPLACE` but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I have a large SKOS taxonomy with URIs that have an incorrect string. They should have this string: "iso-639" but I made a mistake when creating it and put "iso-693". I'd like to correct it. I used the SPARQL query shown below, which when run returns a message "update successful", but none of the triples data actually changes. Where am I going wrong?

```sql
INSERT
{
  ?s ?p ?o2
}

WHERE 
{ 
  ?s ?p ?o .
  FILTER (regex(str(?s), "iso-693") || regex(str(?o), "iso-693"))
  BIND(REPLACE(?o, "iso-693", "iso-639", "i") AS ?o2) .
  }
```

I expected all of the occurrences of the substring to change to the desired value, but nothing seems to change at all despite the success message.

Comment: you are just inserting new data, why do you think that data will be replaced? The `WHERE` part is just to get the solutions bindings and hte `REPLACE` keyword inside just replaces part of the solution bindings to generate the final solution bindings that then will be sued in the `INSERT` clause. What you need is also a `DELETE` part. It should be `DELETE {...} INSERT {...} WHERE {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the bit that removes the old value (`INSERT` just adds a new triples). To replace a triple, you should `DELETE` the old triple at the same time as you are `INSERT`ing the new one, like this:

```
DELETE
{
  ?s ?p ?o 
}
INSERT
{
  ?s ?p ?o2
}
WHERE 
{ 
  ?s ?p ?o .
  FILTER (regex(str(?s), "iso-693") || regex(str(?o), "iso-693"))
  BIND(REPLACE(?o, "iso-693", "iso-639", "i") AS ?o2) .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting URIs then you need to construct new IRIs with the required substitution and use these in the `INSERT` part of the update along with the original values fro `?s` and `?o` for `DELETE` part. The `REPLACE` will produce Literals which is not correct fro subjects.

Suggest using something along following lines:

```
DELETE {
    ?s ?p ?o
}
INSERT {
    ?newS ?p ?newO
} WHERE { 
    ?s ?p ?o .
    bind("iso-693" as ?match) .
    bind("iso-639" as ?replacement) .
    bind (regex(str(?s), ?match) as ?subjMatch) .
    bind (regex(str(?o), ?match) as ?objMatch) .
    filter (?subjMatch || ?objMatch)
    bind (if(?subjMatch, IRI(replace(str(?s), ?match, ?replacement)), ?s) as ?newS)
    bind (if(?objMatch, IRI(replace(str(?o), ?match, ?replacement)), ?o) as ?newO)
}
```